# How I can retrieve the value of a variable from multiple functions running in parallel in Python?

Tags: python

```
import multiprocessing

max=0

def fun_square():

  for i in range (5):

    result = x*x

    return result

  total=max+10

  def main():

    jobs = []

    for i in range(3):

       p = multiprocessing.Process(target=fun_square, args=(i,))

       jobs.append(p)

       p.start()

    for proc in jobs:

       proc.join()

    if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

''''
I want to run 3 fun_square in parallel for 5 iteration,Each iteration, I want to compute the square of x and based on these value said(4,1,9) that coming from all processes, 9 will be selected as max value to compute total. Then go to next iteration.

I used multiprocessing to run the function in parallel but I’m sticking to retrieve the value of square x and update total. Any help for that?

''''

Comment: Please fix your indentation; the code as-is is unintelligible.

Comment: use https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool

Answer (score 0):

Try using a global variable.

At the top of your code put:

`total = 0`

Inside your function, put:

`global total`

And then you can access total, retrieve its value, and update its value inside your function. This is because you told the function to use the variable `total`, that already exists outside the function. It knows not to create new local variable.

Hope that helps!

Comment: are you sure this will work across Python processes? :^)